# Why i can't hit DRF from React?

Tags: reactjs, api, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I want to hit api from react with axios like this

```
axios.get('url', {
   headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer awdoij123pio...' }
})
.then((response) => {
   console.log(response);

}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And got error 'CORS Missing Allow Origin'. In django i already install django corsheader and setting like this.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'corsheaders',
  ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
  ...
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  ...
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
]
```

How can i fix this error ?

Comment: Just to make sure, is your front-end on `http` and not `https` and is on port `3000`?

Comment: yes, it's on ```http``` and on port ```3000```

Comment: Have you allowed request header `Authorization` in your CORS configuration? Since you're including that header in your client code, you should.

Comment: i already tried to allow request header ```Authorization``` but still didn't work

Comment: when i run django in local and i hit from react it works. but when i deploy to server it didn't work